# Get Key State in linux C

Tags: c, linux, winapi, keyboard, arrow-keys

OK ive searched about for quite some time now but i simply cannot find a replacement for the `GetKeyState()` function in linux. All i need and want is to simply poll the arrow keys, and if they are pressed, execute something. My home PC is linux based and my students' PC is windows based, so when i worked in that, i wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
int x; int y, redraw;
int i; int l, xm, ym, op, as, b, ab;
short int display[10][10];

void draw() {
    if (redraw == 1) {
        system("cls");
        while (l < 10) {
            while (i<10) {
                if (display[i][l] == 0) { printf("="); }
                if (display[i][l] == 1) { printf("X"); }
                if (display[i][l] == 2) { printf("w"); }
                if (display[i][l] == 3) { printf("0"); }
                if (display[i][l] == 4) { printf("#"); }
                if (display[i][l] == 5) { printf("M"); }
                if (display[i][l] == 6) { printf("H"); }
                if (display[i][l] == 7) { printf("8"); }
                printf("|");
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            printf("\n");
            printf("-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+");
            printf("\n");
            l++;
        }
        l = 0;
        redraw = 0;
    }
}

void getkeys() {
    while (b == 0) {
        if (GetKeyState(VK_LEFT) & 0x8000)
        {
            xm = -1;
            b = 1;
        }
        if (GetKeyState(VK_RIGHT) & 0x8000)
        {
            xm = 1;
            b = 1;
        }
        if (GetKeyState(VK_UP) & 0x8000)
        {
            ym = -1;
            b = 1;
        }
        if (GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x8000)
        {
            ym = 1;
            b = 1;
        }
        if (GetKeyState(VK_BACK) & 0x8000)
        {
            op = -1;
            b = 1;
        }
        if (GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000)
        {
            op = 1;
            b = 1;
        }

    } b = 0; redraw = 1;
}

void cursor() {
    display[x][y] = as;
    x = x + xm;
    xm = 0;
    y = y + ym;
    ym = 0;
    if (x >9) { x = 0; }
    if (y >9) { y = 0; }
    if (x <0) { x = 9; }
    if (y <0) { y = 9; }
    ab = display[x][y];
    as = ab;
    if (as == 0) {
        display[x][y] = 4;
    }
    if (as == 1) {
        display[x][y] = 5;
    }
    if (as == 2) {
        display[x][y] = 6;
    }
    if (as == 3) {
        display[x][y] = 7;
    }
    Sleep(100);
}

void main()
{
    while (i < 10) {
        while (l<10) { display[l][i] = rand() % 4; l++; } l = 0; i++;
    }
    redraw = 1;
    while (1) {
        draw();
        getkeys();
        b = 0;
        cursor();
    }
}
```

now this basically prints an array and a cursor on it, but it does use the GetKeyState() function and i just can not find an alternative to it on linux. So is there any simple alternative to the mentioned function and is it possible to make the source code multiplatform somehow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code shown is c, not c++.

Comment: Indentation is not optional when asking other people about your code.

Comment: Your best bet is probably a library such as [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) which is cross-platform and very easy to use.

Comment: The whole `if` list can be replaced by a string `"=Xw0#MH8"` indexed by `display[i][l]`.

Comment: Your [GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx) calls won't work the way you think they are: *"The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue. The status does not reflect the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware. Use the [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx) function to retrieve that information."*